# Connect to SQL Server database from RHEL with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, unix, driver, windows-authentication

I have been working for two weeks in the installation of Superset (from Airbnb) for data visualization on a virtual RHEL machine and the connection with a SQL Server database. But I still cannot connect to this database because of a problem of driver I guess. I tried many things and I would like to know if you have a solution, about a driver I need, about modifications in my configuration etc... 
Someone told me about jTDS driver. Maybe I need something like this but for python. If you have any idea, here is what I already did.

1) I tried to connect to the database from Superset :

SQL Alchemy URI : `mssql://user:password@fr0-iacls-190.eu.company.corp:10001/dbname`

```
ERROR : {"error": "Connection failed!\n\n
The error message returned was:\n(pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][DriverManager]
Data source name not found, and no default driver specidied (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')"}
```

2) I tried almost the same with mssql+pymssql :

SQL Alchemy URI : `mssql+pymssql://user:password@fr0-iacls-190.eu.company.corp:10001/dbname`

```
ERROR:{"error":"Connection failed!\n\n
The error message returned was:\n(pymssql.OperationalError) (18456, 'DB-Lib error message 20018,
severity 14:\\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\\n
DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\\n Adaptive Server connection failed (fr0-iacls-190.eu.company.corp:10001)\\n')"}
```

3) I tried to connect to the database from my terminal on virtual RHEL machine :

```
# tsql -S fr0-iacls-190.eu.company.corp -U user
  Password:
  locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
  locale charset is "UTF-8"
  using default charset "UTF-8"
  20^C
```

Here I have a timer that increase the number every second. I stopped the example after 20 seconds.

4) Finally I tried a python script like this one :

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=fr0-iacls-190.eu.company.corp;DATABASE=dbname;UID=;PWD=password')
```

The empty UID is a tip used in another StackOverflow post.

```
# python connect.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect.py", line 2, in <module>
  cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=fr0-iacls-190.eu.company.corp;DATABASE=dbname;UID=;PWD=password')
  pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

To finish, I read about two files, odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini but I don't know if they are in the good directory (/etc). I am not working on root (~) but in in the parent directory of root (cd ~/..)...

Here are the two files if necessary :

odbc.ini

```
;
;  odbc.ini
;
[ODBC Data Sources]
JDBC = Sybase JDBC Server

[JDBC]
Driver          = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Description     = Sybase JDBC Server
Trace           = No
Servername      = JDBC
Database        = pubs2
UID             = guest

[Default]
Driver          = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[PostgreSQL]
Description=ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver=/usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage=1

[MySQL]
Description=ODBC for MySQL
Driver=/usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage=1

[MSSQLTest]
Driver = ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Server = [http:]fr0-iacls-190.eu.company.corp[,10001]
#
# Note:
# Port is not a valid keyword in the ~/.odbc.ini file
# for the Microsoft ODBC driver on Linux
#

[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.4.0
UsageCount=1
```

Many thanks for your time and your help.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

**Correct the python connection string:**

You have the aliased the MS SQL driver in `/etc/odbcinst.ini` to `[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]` therefore in your python code you should be using that, rather than `SQL Server`:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=fr0-iacls-190.eu.company.corp;Port=10001;Database=dbname;UID=user;PWD=password')
```

replacing `user` and `password` with correct credentials.

**Use isql to test a connection using odbc.ini:**

Generally you use the `odbcinst.ini` to setup driver configuration, and then `odbc.ini` for database instances (referencing the drivers), thus a valid entry to your `odbc.ini` could be:

```
[friendly_database_name]
Description=A description to help you remember what this connection is for
Server=fr0-iacls-190.eu.company.corp
Port=10001
Database=dbname
UID=user
PWD=password
```

If you have `isql` installed (comes as part of the `unixODBC` package if not), then you can test with:

```
$ isql -3 -v friendly_database_name
```

**Ensure there's not a firewall blocking you:**

I'm not sure why the tsql command is failing for you, it should return the `1>` prompt. Ensure that you can establish a telnet connection to the database server:

```
$ telnet fr0-iacls-190.eu.company.corp 10001
```

which should give you something like:

```
Trying 12.34.56.78...
Connected to fr0-iacls-190.eu.company.corp.
Escape character is '^]'
```

and then to `ctrl` + `]` and type `quit` to exit (or do `ctrl` + `c` to cancel if the telnet test fails).